# C++ swap/sort algorithm

Tags: sorting, swap

Given the following:

```
Container A; //contains n data entries
vector<int> B; //indexes of A that need to be swapped
vector<int> C; // Where the entry needs to be moved to, a randomly sorted version of B
//B.size() <= A.size() - not all may be swapped
//C.size() = B.size()

swap(container &X, int i, int j); //moves X[i]->X[j] and X[j]->X[i]
```

Here is what I need to do:

For the data in container A, I need to move each index specified in B to the corresponding index in C using a swap function. I cannot create another Container in the process. There is also the chance that an index marked to be sorted may not move (B[i] = C[i]).

For example:

```
A=[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j];
B=[0, 1, 3, 6, 9]; //move these entries to....
C= [3, 6, 9, 0, 1]; //these entries
```

After running the algorithm A would look like this:

```
A=[g, j, c, a, e, f, b, h, i, d]
```

Does anyone have a good solution to this? I've been raking my brain the past few days over this.

Comment: That should never happen.

Comment: C is a randomly sorted version of B

Comment: Basically A[B[0]] -> A[C[0]], A[B[1]] -> A[C[1]], and so on. What makes it difficult is that I have to do this all within container A using its built in swap function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sequence of swaps gives the result you want:

- swap(0,3)
- swap(0,9)
- swap(0,1)
- swap(0,6)

So the algorithm would be:

```
Let x = B[0], y = C[0], odd = true
do length(A)-1 times:
    swap( x, y )
    if odd:
        set i such that B[i] = y
        y = C[i]
    else:
        set i such that C[i] = y
        y = B[i]
    odd = not odd
```

Comment: I implemented this into our code. I currently do not have the correct hardware to test the code so I sent it to the lab. Fingers are crossed, thank you!

Comment: IT seems to be working unfortunately it was overwritten. I wrote basically the same thing as what you had but the person testing it did not understand so they wrote new code. Their problem now!